# How to combine multiple data frames into a single violinplot and add a swarmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have two data frames, with different shapes. I'd like to plot the two data frame values of the violin plots next to each other instead of overlapping.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = {
    'DT' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 100),
    'RF' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 110),
    'KNN' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 120)
}
maxsize = max([a.size for a in data1.values()])
data_pad1 = {k:np.pad(v, pad_width=(0,maxsize-v.size,), mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan) for k,v in data1.items()}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_pad1) # data frame

data2 = {
    'DT' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 50),
    'RF' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 60),
    'KNN' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 80)
}

maxsize = max([a.size for a in data2.values()])
data_pad2 = {k:np.pad(v, pad_width=(0,maxsize-v.size,), mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan) for k,v in data2.items()}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_pad2) # dataframe2 

#plotting 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
ax = sns.violinplot(data=df1, color="blue")
ax = sns.violinplot(data=df2, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Here is my output image.

[image: Output image]

But I'd like to get each blue and red violin plot next to each other instead of overlapping. I'd further like to show the datapoints via a swarm plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn works easiest with data in "long form".  You can create such a dataframe directly from the given dictionaries without the need to fill up with NaNs.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'DT': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 100),
         'RF': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 110),
         'KNN': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 120)}
data2 = {'DT': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 50),
         'RF': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 60),
         'KNN': np.random.normal(-1, 1, 80)}

df = pd.DataFrame([[label, val, 'data1'] for label, values in data1.items() for val in values]
                  + [[label, val, 'data2'] for label, values in data2.items() for val in values],
                  columns=['label', 'value', 'source'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['cornflowerblue', 'indianred'], ax=ax)
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')  # remove labels set by seaborn
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.violinplot from 2 dataframes with different sizes]

PS: To combine the violin plot with a swarm plot, you also need `hue=` and `dodge=True` e.g. `sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['black', 'black'], dodge=True, ax=ax)`.  You might also want to remove the existing `inner` of the `violinplot`.

```py
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['cornflowerblue', 'indianred'], saturation=1, inner=None, ax=ax)
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['black', 'black'], dodge=True, legend=False, ax=ax)
```

[image: combining violinplot and swarmplot with hue]

Alternatively, you could create a split violinplot:

```py
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['lightgrey', 'lightyellow'], saturation=0.5,
               inner=None, split=True, ax=ax)
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['cornflowerblue', 'indianred'], ax=ax)
```

[image: split sns.violinplot together with sns.swarmplot]

Comment: You can use `sns.violinplot(..., saturation=1)` if you'd want more vivid colors.

Comment: thank you, If try to display the data points below the violin plots, it's not working. sns.swarmplot(data=df, color="black", ax=ax). can you please display the data points also ?

Comment: Writing *"it's not working"* isn't very informative.  If you want the dots separated by "hue", you need `hue=` and `dodge=True` e.g. `sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='label', y='value', hue='source', palette=['black', 'black'], dodge=True, ax=ax)`.  You might also want to remove the existing `inner` of the `violinplot`, like `sns.violinplot(data=df, ..., inner=None)`. (Other options for `inner` are `“box”, “quartile”, “point”, “stick”`.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest relabeling the columns in each dataframe to reflect the dataframe number, *e.g.*:

```
data2 = {
    'DT2' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 50),
    'RF2' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 60),
    'KNN2' : np.random.normal(-1, 1, 80)
}
```

You may then:

1. concatenate both dataframes:

   df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
2. define your own palette:

   my_palette = {"DT1": "blue", "DT2": "red","KNN1": "blue", "KNN2": "red", "RF1": "blue", "RF2": "red"}
3. and then force the plotting order using the `order` parameter:

   sns.violinplot(data=df, order = ['DT1', 'DT2', 'KNN1', 'KNN2', 'RF1', 'RF2'], palette=my_palette)

This yields the following result:

[image]

**EDIT:**

You may manually set the labels to replace each label pair (*e.g.* DT1, DT2) with a single label (*e.g.* DT):

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()  # Get the current locations and labels.
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, 4.5, step=2))  # Set label locations.
plt.xticks([0.5, 2.5, 4.5], ['DT', 'KNN', 'RFF'])  # Set text labels.
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: I tried this idea. is it possible to get the x-tick value in between the red and blue violin?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a suggestion on how to improve labelling.