# Layer Python Seaborn and then Save to Disk

Tags: python, seaborn, jpeg

I am trying to layer a swarmplot on top of a violin chart just like the seaborn documentation has here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html
But in that example they are just displaying to the screen so the following works

```
sns.catplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", kind="violin", color=".9", inner=None)
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", size=3)
```

But I need to save to a file like so..

```
cat_plot = sns.catplot ([args go here])
cat_plot.savefig ([args])
```

How do I add a swarmplot to my cat_plot FacetGrid so when I save it they are layered on top of each other in the resulting jpg?  Or is there another way I should be trying to accomplish this?

Comment: `sns.catplot` creates a grid with one or more subplots.  If you only have one subplot, you can directly use `ax = sns.violinplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", color=".9", inner=None)` and use `plt.savefig(...)` afterward. See also [how to plot the multiple data frames on a single violin plot next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680995)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.catplot` returns a `FacetGrid` with one or more subplots. When there is only one subplot, the subsequent `sns.swarmplot()` will draw onto that same subplot.  Afterward, you can simply save the figure, which will include the original `catplot` together with all elements that have been added, either via other seaborn functions, or directly via matplotlib.

As `catplot` can create multiple subplots, the recommended way to add a `smarmplot` to all of them would be via `g.map_dataframe(sns.swarmplot, x="age", y="class", size=3)`. (But as there is only one subplot in your example, your code also works with calling `sns.swarmplot` directly.)

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
g = sns.catplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", kind="violin", color=".9", inner=None)
g.map_dataframe(sns.swarmplot, x="age", y="class", size=3)
g.savefig('combined-violin-swarmplot.png')
```

[image: combined violinplot swarmplot]